# Overwriting undefined and IIFE in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have been reading the "You Don't Know Js" series and came across this:

> "Another application of this pattern addresses the (minor niche) concern that the default `undefined` identifier might have its value incorrectly overwritten, causing unexpected results. By naming a parameter `undefined`, but not passing any value for that argument, we can guarantee that the `undefined` identifier is in fact the `undefined` value in a block of code: "

```js
undefined = true; // setting a land-mine for other code! avoid!

(function IIFE(undefined) {

  var a;
  if (a === undefined) {
    console.log("Undefined is safe here!");
  }

})();
```

I don't understand what's happening here. Is undefined a data type or just an identifier and how this code works?

Thanks.

Comment: inside of the `function IIFE( undefined ) {` body `undefined` is the parameter with the name `undefined`, because you call this function without an argument, the value of that parameter is `undefined`.

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't understand neither the comment nor the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`undefined` (the identifier) is a predefined global variable whose value is, confusingly, `undefined`, which is the only member of the type Undefined. ([I kid you not](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-terms-and-definitions-undefined-type).)

It **used** to be that `undefined` (the identifier) wasn't read-only, and you could assign to it. That stopped being true a long time ago (2009, as of ES5); this logs `undefined`, not `true`:

```js
undefined = true;
console.log(undefined);
```

...but that's the "niche concern" that section is describing.

A *different*, but genuine, niche concern here in 2018 is that you can *shadow* the `undefined` identifier and give it any value you want:

```js
(function() {
    var undefined = true;
    console.log(undefined); // true
})();
```

So if your code may be plopped in the middle of other code, you could be dealing with a different `undefined` identifer than the global one.

**So**, to deal with that exceptionally-unlikely occurrence, you can write code that shadows `undefined`, but with the correct value, by using an IIFE that declares it as a parameter, and then not passing in any value; the value the parameter will receive will be the actual value `undefined`:

```js
(function() {
    var undefined = true;
    //  ^---- a local variable that shadows (hides) the global
    console.log(undefined); // true
    
    (function(undefined) {
    //        ^---- a parameter that shadows (hides) the one above
        console.log(undefined); // undefined
    })(); // <== Notice we aren't passing any argument for the parameter here
})();
```

Since we don't pass a parameter, the parameter receives the **value** `undefined` (regardless of what value the `undefined` identifier might hold in any given scope).

Comment: Thank you! Just to check my understanding: There is a global default variable called undefined which holds the value undefined(if not overwritten) which itself is the only member of the object Undefined. Right?

Comment: After some thinking, mind blowing and meditation the truth was seen: Undefined is a data type, undefined is its only possible value and undefined is a global default variable

Comment: @BranTran - Yup, exactly. :-) It is *very* weird. Whereas `null` is a keyword for the `null` value (the only member of the Null type), `undefined` isn't a keyword, just a predefined global.

Answer (score 1):

The use of a parameter of a function without a handed over value is `undefined`, despite of the naming.

```
(function IIFE(undefined) {
})();          ^^^^^^^^^
  ^^ --------------+
```

```js
undefined = true; // setting a land-mine for other code! avoid!

(function IIFE(undefined) {
    var a;
    if (a === undefined) {
        console.log("Undefined is safe here!");
    }
})();
```

Comment: `undefined = true` (with the predefined global) stopped having any effect as of ES5, back in 2009.

Comment: Am i right that when this function is invoked it has a parameter named "undefined" which shadows the default identifier "undefined" for a special data type, then, as no value is passed as an argument, the parameter is set to undefined which was explicitly set to true?

Comment: Will (after this point) variables declared and not initialized be set to true?

Comment: yes and no. defined variables, but not initialized variables have the value (and state) `undefined` this does not change if the variable `undefined` has a different value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it’s easier to understand if the parameter isn’t named “undefined” (which isn’t necessary for this to work)

```
undefined = true;
function f ( param ) {
    console.log( 'Param is:', param )
}
f();
-> Param is: undefined
```

It was still possible to access the value `undefined` inside the function, even though it was globally overwritten.